# arm-none-eabi-g++ system include path

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

I have following header file Foo.h:

```
#ifndef _FOO_H_
#define _FOO_H_

#include <type_traits>

class FooC
{
public:
    FooC();
   ~FooC() = default;
};

#endif // _FOO_H_
```

and the corresponding source file Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

FooC::FooC()
{
}
```

I can compile the source file with following command

```
C:\\GNU-Tools-ARM-Embedded\\6-2017-q2-update\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe -IC:/gnu-tools-arm-embedded/6-2017-q2-update/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/6.3.1 -std=gnu++14 -o Foo.cpp.obj -c Foo.cpp
```

or

```
C:\\GNU-Tools-ARM-Embedded\\7-2018-q2-update\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe -IC:/gnu-tools-arm-embedded/7-2018-q2-update/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1 -std=gnu++14 -o Foo.cpp.obj -c Foo.cpp
```

but when I exchange the *-IC:/gnu-tools-arm-embedded/...* with *-isystem C:/gnu-tools-arm-embedded/...*

```
C:\\GNU-Tools-ARM-Embedded\\6-2017-q2-update\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe -isystem C:/gnu-tools-arm-embedded/6-2017-q2-update/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/6.3.1 -std=gnu++14 -o Foo.cpp.obj -c Foo.cpp
```

or

```
C:\\GNU-Tools-ARM-Embedded\\7-2018-q2-update\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-g++.exe -isystem C:/gnu-tools-arm-embedded/7-2018-q2-update/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1 -std=gnu++14 -o Foo.cpp.obj -c Foo.cpp
```

then I get many compile errors like:

```
In file included from Foo.h:4:0,
                 from Foo.cpp:1:
C:/gnu-tools-arm-embedded/6-2017-q2-update/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/6.3.1/type_traits:68:3: error: template with C linkage
   template<typename _Tp, _Tp __v>
   ^~~~~~~~
...
    C:/gnu-tools-arm-embedded/6-2017-q2-update/arm-none-eabi/include/c++/6.3.1/type_traits:2660:3: error: template with C linkage
       template<typename _Tp>
       ^~~~~~~~
```

I need this include path and the include of *type_traits* and can not change to *-I*. Does somebody know a nice solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1698539

Comment: Seems resolved with
GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain
Version 9-2020-q2-update :)